# how to verify if the schedule cron is working on serverless framework

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, cron, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

i have a 2 lambda functions the first one gets an instance ec2 the second one check status of ec2, i added a schedule events to the second one, a cron witch rates every 15 min, so now i want to verify if my status function is really called every 15 min, i have checked on the triggers in aws console, but nothing happend i wonder what did i do wrong?

here is my handler.py file

```
import sys
import schedule
import time
import logging


# Import local dependencies
sys.path.append('./site-packages')

import os
from pprint import pprint
import traceback
import json

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def get_instance(client, event):


instance_name = None
instance_id = None
instance_state = None
error_message = None

# Get the instance name from the path
try:
    instance_name = event['pathParameters']['name']
    print( 'Instance Name: %s' % instance_name)
except:
    instance_name = None

if instance_name:
    r = client.describe_instances(
            Filters=[{'Name':'tag:Name', 'Values': [instance_name]}]
        )
    # AWS' boto3 api involves a lot of looping
    if len(r['Reservations']) > 0:
        for res in r['Reservations']:
            for ins in res['Instances']:
                ins_id = ins['InstanceId']
                ins_state = ins['State']['Name']
                if ins_state in ('shutting-down', 'terminated'):
                   error_message = 'No action taken. Instance %s is %s' %(ins_id, ins_state)
                else:
                    instance_id = ins_id
                    instance_state = ins_state
                break
    else:
        error_message = 'Unable to find instance with tag:Name - %s' %instance_name
else:
    error_message = 'No instance name specified'

print(error_message, instance_name, instance_id, instance_state)
return (error_message, instance_name, instance_id, instance_state)    

def ec2_status(event, context):
"""Take an instance tag:name via an API call and return its status"""
body = {}
status_code = 200

try:
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    # Find the instance
    error, instance_name, instance_id, instance_state = get_instance(client, event)
    if error:
        body["message"] = error
    else:
        body["message"] = str(instance_id) + ' ' + str(instance_state)
except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    status_code = 500
    body["message"] = str(e)

response = {
    "statusCode": status_code,
    "body": json.dumps(body)
}
return response
```

and here is my .yml file

```
service: ec2-remote

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: python2.7
    stage: dev
    region: us-east-1
    memorySize: 128
    versionFunctions: false
    cfLogs: true
    iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
              - "ec2:DescribeInstances"
          Resource: "*" package:
    exclude:
        - .npmignore
        - bin/** functions:
    ec2-status:
        handler: handler.ec2_status
        description: Status ec2 instances
        timeout: 30
        events:
            - http:
                path: ec2/status/{name}
                method: get
                private: false
            - schedule:
              description: my scheduled rate event 
              rate: rate(15 minutes)     resources:
    Resources:
        Ec2DashstatusLogGroup:
            Properties:
                RetentionInDays: "7"
```

Comment: You verify it in the same way you verify cron in a linux system -- check the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can see the execution logs in Cloudwatch -> Log Groups-> "LogGroupFunctionName"